# Artifactory Cloud login screen shows up despite having anonymous access enabled

Tags: maven, user-interface, artifactory

I've had my artifactory cloud instance running for over a year and never had any problems. However, one of my users recently pointed out they can't access the web UI despite anonymous access being enabled.

It turns out Artifactory shows a login screen to unauthenticated users, with a hardly visible exit button in the top right corner. After pressing the button, the login screen will disappear for a second, and then show up again.

[image: Login Screen]

My settings:

- User Management Settings: Anonymous Access is enabled

[image: User Management Settings]

- The Login Screen is disabled for the anonymous user

[image: Login Screen is disabled]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is an expected behaviour based on the improvement on Artifactory 7.37.13, you can refer to this [release note](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#ArtifactoryReleaseNotes-Artifactory7.37.13:%7E:text=Anonymous%20Users%20can%20be%20routed%20to%20Login%20Page%20by%20Default).
If you would like to disable this, do navigate to the Administration --> User Management --> Users and select the anonymous user and uncheck the "Set the Login page as the start page" as below screenshot suggests,
[image]

Comment: Yes, as you can see on my second screenshot, the login screen setting is disabled on my instance. However, artifactory ignores this and still shows the screen.

Comment: Can you test it out in an incognito mode?